# Google Drive sharing dialog (Javascript SDK) doesn't work over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, https, google-drive-api

I've been unable to make the Drive sharing dialog ([as described here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app)) work when HTTPS is used. When I try to open the dialog the following error is printed twice in the JS console:

> [blocked] The page at 'https://...' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran
>   insecure content from
>   'http://www.google.com/intl/pl/drive/about.html': this content should
>   also be loaded over HTTPS.

After a while the following message is shown inside the dialog

> Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time. Please try again later.

I had a look at some existing websites which make use of the sharing dialog and they suffer from the same issue - for example have a look at draw.io or drivenotepad.appspot.com.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there a solution?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.  What browser are you using and is it possible your problem is due to a plugin/extension..try using a different computer/browser or run your browser in incognito/private mode.

Comment: @dan-man - Oh believe me I tried various machines and browsers before posting this. For example try to use the sharing dialog on draw.io - does it work for you?

Comment: draw.io and drivenotepad both work for me (I am the dev of drivenotepad).

Comment: @dan-man judging by the upvotes and the answer-comment below I'd say I'm not the only person experiencing this issue. Are you sure you didn't set your browser to load mixed/insecure content?

Comment: Just tried on Chrome OS and Win7+Chrome/Firefox/IE and all work fine (if I did meddle with command line flags at some point I doubt I did it in all 4 places)...in other words your problem may be more niche than you'd thought...have you tried multiple accounts and languages?